# Text Format in Excel using VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

When I use WinSQL to run a SQL statement, the result is 20100803000001812. However, when I incorporate the SQL as a macro, the result is 2.01008E+16. What should I do in the macro in order to maintain the result as 20100803000001812 ?

Thanks,

Bob

Comment: Is it a large integer number or a text (looks like YYYYMMDDHHMMSSMMM)?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/651fe1d2-347a-4ab9-a40f-0d503af2cca7/fix-excel-text-displayed.aspx) `ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "@"` should do the trick.

Comment: I hv inserted it into the macro & yet, it doesn't work. It's still shows as 2.01008E+16.

Comment: As suggested by Tahbaza on 4 Oct 2010, an apostrophe if you're just wanting the column to display as text, something like :- select Cno,Itno,CONCAT('''',Ref) as Ref from test.

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveCell.NumberFormat = "0"` works for me (not what I expected, but so it goes)

You might want to throw in a `Cells.Columns.AutoFit` to resize the columns as necessary.

Comment: @Bob - Where are you putting this code in? What if you try setting the number format manually?

Comment: Someone suggested to add CONCAT to my select statement & it works (eg. select Cno,Itno,CONCAT('''',Ref) as Ref from test)

Comment: @Bob good that you got it figured out. You should post the solution and accept that as your answer to close out the question.